# BST insertion and traversal error being thrown

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, traversal, insertion

I am trying to insert all of these methods without recursion and when I run it in the main method it throws this error and I do not know why. I have used multiple files and classes and import them in order to use them globally. I have tried taking self out but it throws the same error. Any help with this would be great.

This is the Node class file.

```
#Node.py 
class Node:
    data = None
    leftchild = None
    rightchild = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.leftchild = None
        self.rightchild = None
```

This is the BinarySearchTree class file

```
#binarSearchTre.py

from _collections import deque
from Node import Node




class BinarySearchTree():
    root=None
    
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

  

        def preorder(self, root):
            if root is None:
                return
        
                nodeStack= deque()
                nodeStack.append(root)
               
            
            while nodeStack:
            
                curr=nodeStack.pop()
            print (curr.data, end='')
            
            if curr.rightChild:
                nodeStack.append(curr.rightChild)
            if curr.leftChild:
                nodeStack.append(curr.leftChild)
            
            
        def inorder(self,root):
            
            current = root  
            stack = deque() 
            
            
            while True:
                
                if current is not None: 
                    
                    stack.append(current) 
          
                    current = current.leftchild
                    
                elif(stack): 
                    
                    current = stack.pop() 
                    print(current.data, end=" ") 
                    
                    current = current.rightchild
                
                else:
                    break
                    print()
        
        
        def postorder(self,root):
            
            stack=deque()
            stack.append(root)
            out=deque()
            while stack:
                curr=stack.pop()
                out.append(curr.data)
                
                if curr.__leftchild:
                    stack.append(curr.leftchild)
                if curr.__rightchild:
                    stack.append(curr.rightchild)
                    
            while out:
                
                print(out.pop(), end='')
                
        def insertNode(self,root,data):
            
            curr=root
            parent=None
            
            if root is None:
                return Node(data)
            
            while curr:
                
                parent=curr
                
                if data<curr.data:
                    curr=curr.leftchild
                else:
                    curr=curr.rightchild
                    
                if data<parent.data:
                    parent.leftchild=Node(data)
                else:
                    parent.rightchild=Node(data)
                    
                    return root
```

This is the main file.

```
#main.py
from binarSearchTre import BinarySearchTree

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    BST1=BinarySearchTree()
    BST2=BinarySearchTree()
    root=None
    root= BST1.insertNode(root,4)
    root= BST1.insertNode(root,1)
    root= BST1.insertNode(root,9)
    root= BST1.insertNode(root,12)
    root= BST1.insertNode(root,3)
    root= BST1.insertNode(root,2)
    root= BST1.insertNode(root,8)
    root= BST1.insertNode(root,7)
    root= BST1.insertNode(root,16)
    root= BST1.insertNode(root,20)
    root= BST1.insertNode(root,13)
    root= BST1.insertNode(root,11)
    
    
 
   
                    
    print ("preorder traversal of the given tree")
    print(BST1.preorder(root))
```

This is the error it is throwing. It has something to do with how im calling the insert node method. I guess im not doing it correctly. Any advice/help would be great.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owen Averill\eclipse-workspace\BST\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    root= BST1.insertNode(root,4)
AttributeError: 'BinarySearchTree' object has no attribute 'insertNode'
```

Comment: You seem to have multiple variables named "root" in your code.  Both the top-level one in your main, and the instance variable that is part of BinarySearchTree.  I look at something like your call to `preorder`, where you get a value `root` as an argument, but then push `self.root`.   The root of the tree is an internal detail of the BST and should never appear outside of it.   Delete every occurrence of root that is outside the class definition; this will help you stop being confused.  Your only use of root,getting and setting, should be self.root

Comment: I'm also not positive, but when you have root=None at the start of BinarySearchTree, that will make root into a class variable.  You don't want that.  Your self.root = None inside the `__init__` is correct.

Comment: @FrankYellin while you're right that `root` should be an *internal implementation detail* of a BST, and declared outside, there is nothing *technically wrong* with having a global variable called `root` and an instance field `BST.root` - the two are entirely separate. Assignment of `root = None` does not affect `BST.root` in any way *at the time of the assignment*.

Comment: @CoolBots. Yes, you are right.  But the problem is that the code is confusing the two variables and using the wrong one at various places.  I'm assuming this is a homework assignment.  I'm trying to say what's wrong with the code (you've got two different roots) without writing the code for them.

Comment: @CoolBots.  So yeah. two different variables is fine.  Two different variable representing the same thing, and sometimes updating one and sometimes updating the other, not cool.  And while we're at it, we might as well encourage good class design.  I hope you agree.